# How to write and read file in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a problem with saving files and then downloading them after generating a .war file.
I need to handle the generation of many files after pressing the button by admin in the application. The files are generated using part of the code that was sent using the POST method and second part is from the database.
The files are hundreds / thousands and it is impossible to do it manually. Admin generates files from time to time. The user should be able to download these files from the application.
When I run the application in IntelliJ, app has access to the folders on the disk, so the following code works:
(part of backend class, responfible for saving files in path)

```
    private void saveTextToFile(String text, String fileName) {
        String filePathAndName = "/static/myFiles/" + fileName+ ".txt";
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(".").getFile() + filePathAndName );
        FileWriter fileWriter = null;
        try {
            fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
            printWriter.print(text);
            printWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The file was saved in folder:
*C:\Users...\myProject\target\classes\static*.
(and this is link to generated file in thymeleaf)

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<a th:href="@{|/myFiles/${thisIsMyFileName}|}">Download file</a>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, when I generate the .war file and run it, the files are not saved in the application's "resources" folder. As a result, the user cannot download this file via the link generated by thymeleaf.

Comment: why not store your files in a DB and have your code get/store it (from) there?

Comment: I don't quite understand, why you have to save the files to disk? If you want to deliver files to a user on keypress, you could do it on the fly, right?

Comment: This is a solution. I would have to store it as a String. Then the user could have access to the text, but I don't know how to convert the text to a file that would be automatically downloaded.

Comment: @Frischling I could do it on the fly. However, I would prefer to save it.

Comment: You cannot save files to the classpath (at least NOT inside the WAR/JAR). You can save it to an outside accessible path like a temp folder or specifically assigned folder for that.

Comment: @MarcinFrąckiewicz then you have to save the stuff to an external folder, dedicated for this.  Database I find a bad idea somehow.  But really, if there are no concrete performance reasons or similar - creation on the fly is the way to go...  You also have to manage the directory, make the test-cases work + do a different file resolution in prod, and in the end have more effort, so asking _for what_ does have its justification.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you do not want to upload anything into your application's files - it opens you to many security problems if someone figures out how to overwrite parts of the application, and in most application servers, it is simply not writable.

A much better approach is to have a designated server folder where you can write things. For example, you could have the following in your configuration:

```
myapp.base-folder = /any/server/folder/you/want
```

And then, in the code, you would find that folder as follows:

```
// env is an @AutoWired private Environment
File baseFolder = new File(env.getProperty("myapp.base-folder"));
```

I find this better than using a database (as @Stultuske suggested in comments), because databases are great for relations, but mostly overkill for actual files. Files can be accessed externally without firing up the database with minimal hassle, and having them separate keeps your database much easier to backup.

To generate links to the file, simply create a link as you would to any other type of request

```
<a th:href="@{/file/${fileId}|}">Download file</a>
```

-- and to handle it in the server, but returning the contents of the file:

```
@GetMapping(value="/file/{id}")
public StreamingResponseBody getFile(@PathVariable long id) throws IOException {        
    File f = new File(baseFolder, ""+id); // numerical id prevents filesytem traversal
    InputStream in;
    if (f.exists()) {
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
    } else {
        // you could also signal error by returning a 404
        in = new BufferedInputStream(getClass().getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("static/img/unknown-id.jpg"));
    }
    return new StreamingResponseBody() {
        @Override
        public void writeTo(OutputStream os) throws IOException {
            FileCopyUtils.copy(in, os);
        }
    };
}
```

I prefer numerical IDs to avoid [hassles with path traversal](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Path_Traversal) - but you can easily use string filenames instead, and deal with security issues by carefully checking that the canonical path of the requested file starts with the canonical path of your `baseFolder`